# How to get the href and associated information using scrapy?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy but using python for a while. I took lesson from the `scrapy` docs along with the `xpath` selectors. Now, I would like to turn the knowledge to do a small project. I'm trying to scrap the `job links and the associated info like job title, location, emails (if any), phone numbers (if any)` from the job board `https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/` using the scrapy.

I have this starter code,

```
import scrapy   

class GermanSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    # spider name 
    name = 'germany'

    # the first page of the website 
    start_urls= ['https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/']
    print start_urls

    def parse(self, response):
        pass 

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        pass
```

and will run the spider `scrapy runspider germany`

Inside the `parse` function, I would like to get the `href`s and details inside the `parse_detail` function.

When, I opened the mentioned page with `chrome` developer tools and inspect the listed jobs,  I see that all the jobs are inside this `ul`

```
<ul id="job-listing-view" class="job_listings job-listings-table-bordered">
```

and then, the separates jobs are listed in the many inside `divs` of

`<div class="job-info-row-listing-class">` with associate infos, say, the `href` is provided inside `<a href="https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/job/foodpanda-berlin-germany-2-sem-manager-mf/">`

Other `divs` provides job title, company name, location etc with `divs` such as

```
          <div>
            <h4 class="job-title-class">
              SEM Manager (m/f)            </h4>
          </div>

          <div class="job-company-name">
            <normal>foodpanda<normal>          </normal></normal></div>
          </div>

  <div class="location">
      <div class="job-location-class"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>
        Berlin, Germany          </div>
    </div>
```

The first step will be to get the `href` using the `parse` function and then, the associated info inside the `parse_details` using the `response`. I find that the `email` and the `phone` number only provided when you will open the links from the `href`s but the title and location is provided inside the current `divs` of the same page.

As I mentioned, I have okay programming skill in python, but, I struggles with the using `xpath`s even after having this [tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/selectors.html). How do find the links and associated info ? Some sample code with little explanation will help a lot.

I try using the code

```
    # firstly 
    for element in response.css("job-info-row-listing-class"):

        href = element.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
        print href
        yield scrapy.Request(href, callback=self.parse_detail)

    # secondly 
    values = response.xpath('//div[@class="job-info-row-listing-class"]//a/text()').extract()

    for v in values:
        print v


    # 
    values = response.xpath('//ul[@id="job-listing-view"]//div[@class="job-info-row-listing-class"]//a/text()').extract()
```

They seems return nothing so far after runing the spider using `scrapy runspider germany`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably won't be able to extract the information on this site that easily, since the actual job-listings are loaded as a POST-request.

How do you know this?

- Type `scrapy shell "https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/"` in your terminal of choice. (This opens up the, you guessed it, shell, which is highly recommendable, when first starting to scrape a website. There you can try out functions, xpaths etc.)
- In the shell, type `view(response)`. This opens the response scrapy is getting in your default browser.
- When the page has finished loading, you should be able to see, that there are no job listings. This is because they are loaded through a POST-Request.

How do we find out what request it is? (I work with Firebug for FireFox, don't know how it works on Chrome)

- Fire up firebug (e.g. by right-clicking on an element and clicking `Inspect with Firebug`. This opens up Firebug, which is essentially like the Developer tools in Chrome. I prefer it.
- Here you can click the `Network`-Tab. If there is nothing there, reload the page.
- Now you should be able to see the request with which the job listings are loaded.

In this case, the request to `https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/jm-ajax/get_listings/`  returns a `JSON`-object (click `JSON`) with the HTML-code as aprt of it.

For your spider this means that you will need to tell scrapy to get this request and process the `HTML`-part of the `JSON`-object in order to be able to apply your xpaths.

You do this by import the `json`-module at the top of your spider and then something along the lines of:

```
data = json.loads(response.body)
html = data['html']
selector = scrapy.Selector(text=data['html'], type="html")
```

For example, if you'd like to extract all the urls from the site and follow them, you'd need to specify the xpath, where to urls are found and `yield` a new request to this url. So basically you're telling scrapy "Look, here is the url, now go and follow it".

An example for an xpath would be:

```
url = selector.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
```

So everything in the brackets is your xpath. You don't need to specify all the path from `ul[@id="job-listing-view"]/` or so, you just need to make sure it is an identifiable path. Here for example, we only have the urls in the `a`-tags that you want, there are no other `a`-tags on the site.

This is pretty much the basic stuff.

I strongly recommend you to play around in the shell until you feel you get a hang of the xpaths. Take a site that looks quite easy, without any requests and see if you can find any element you want through the xpaths.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and this is really helpful. I posted another question related to `scrapy` that may be interesting for you `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178659/how-to-get-the-job-description-using-scrapy`