# How to get the job description using scrapy?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm new to `scrapy` and `XPath` but programming in Python for sometime. I would like to get the `email`, `name of the person making the offer` and `phone` number from the page `https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/job/joblift-berlin-germany-3-working-student-offpage-seo-french-market/` using scrapy. As you see, the email and phone is provided as text inside the `<p>` tag and that makes it hard to extract.

My idea is to first get text inside the `Job Overview` or at least all the text talking about this respective job and use `ReGex` to get the `email`, `phone number` and if possible the `name of the person`.

So, I fired up the `scrapy shell` using the command: `scrapy shell https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/job/joblift-berlin-germany-3-working-student-offpage-seo-french-market/` and get the `response` from there.

Now, I try to get all the text from the div `job_description` where I actually get nothing. I used

```
full_des = response.xpath('//div[@class="job_description"]/text()').extract()
```

It returns `[u'\t\t\t\n\t\t   ']`

How do I get all the text from the page mentioned ? Obviously, the task will come afterwards to get the attributes mentioned before, but, first things first.

Update: This selection only returns `[]`  `response.xpath('//div[@class="job_description"]/div[@class="container"]/div[@class="row"]/text()').extract()`

[image]

Comment: after the div[@class="job_description"] you immediately go to div[@class="container"], so you skipped one element called "section". you can inluce it in the xpath query, or use //, e.g.  div[@class="job_description"]//div[@class="container"]/.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close with

```
full_des = response.xpath('//div[@class="job_description"]/text()').extract()
```

The `div`-tag actually does not have any text besides what you get.

```
<div class="job_description" (...)>
    "This is the text you are getting"
    <p>"This is the text you want"</p>
</div>
```

As you see, the text you are getting with `response.xpath('//div[@class="job_description"]/text()').extract()` is the text that is **in between** the `div`-tag, not in between the tags inside the `div`-tag. For this you would need:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="job_description"]//*/text()').extract()
```

What this does is it selects all the child-nodes from `div[@class="job_description]` and returns the text (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) for what the different xpaths do).

You will see that this returns much useless text as well, as you are still getting all the `\n` and such. For this I suggest that you narrow your xpath down to the element that you want, instead of doing a broad approach.

For example the entire job description would be in

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-5 justify-text"]//*/text()').extract()
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I posted a follow up question that might be interesting for you to answer `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194574/how-to-find-all-the-jobs-listed-in-a-website`